# How to bring app in foreground when a push notification is received

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am trying to make an app with Expo CLI that will alert me if something happens with my servers. I implemented push notifications with expo-push-notifications, but I need the app to wake me up if anything happens.

How could I bring the app in foreground when a notification is received even if the app is killed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't launch an application that is in the background or killed state via push notification. The user needs to click on the notification in order the application to launch. You can run a background task when notification is received if that is helping your use case.

Comment: I want the app to ring an alarm when a notification is received. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use Push Notification or Local Notification, to play a sound.

Comment: I use push notifications but I need something that will play a sound more than a simple notification, just like an alarm. I used critical alerts for iOS, but is there something better to do this?

Comment: Critical alert is good because ignores the sound switch. Have you tried to setup an alarm whenever you receive the event?

Comment: So am I able to run an alarm when I receive a notification, an alarm that is like the alarms someone uses to wake them up in the morning?